# "attrib -s -h *.* /s /d" access denied errors

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, attributes

My problem is that my usb flash drive doesn't show the contents and I  searched it on Google I find the solution for this error. But When I type the command from cmd as administrator it gives me access denied all contents of system32 files. (My OS is win8-pro-64bit)

- I tried changing the ownership of system32 and all its contents as user/myusername
- I tried changing the ownership as everyone.

All of two doesn't solve the annoying errors.
Also

- I tried to open it on ubuntu os it shows all of the contents. And there is no errors.
- I tried to write new mbr via using testdisk to solve problem but still I have same issue.

Comment: are you sure you're in the right directory?

Comment: No I am at win/system32 and when I typed cd e:   it doesn't navigate to e

Comment: You have to change the directory to the flash drive.

just type "e:" without cd

Comment: When I type cd e: it shows me E:\ but  console start with c:\>

Comment: type in the command line "echo %cd%". What are you getting?

Comment: It shows only c:

Comment: how about try "attrib -s -h E:\\*.* /s /d"

Comment: Use the following `cd /d e:` (`/d` means change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder.)

Comment: @DavidPostill thaks for your help

Comment: Well did it work?

Comment: @David your last answer also works to navigate to e

Answer (score 3):

Use    `attrib -s -h E:\*.* /s /d` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to take ownership of the file before you can use attrib. This is the complete answer:

```
icacls <somefile> /grant everyone:f 
attrib -h -s <somefile>
```

via: https://superuser.com/a/1046855/1712122

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).